# jQuery: Animations occur simultaneously instead of back-to-back with .each() iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, methods, each

I am iterating through an array of ".mini" class objects. For each object, each object will wait 500 milliseconds (setTimeout Function) before moving (calling go function). For example,

```
function iterate() {
    $(".mini").each(function(index)
    {
        var element = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {go(element)}, 500);
    });
}

function go(element) {
    element.animate({left: "500px"},200);
}
```

However, the animations for each element are happening all at once (all 32 .mini objects move at once) instead of one moving after the other. How can it so the first one starts moving after 500 seconds from start time, the second one starts after 1000 from start time, etc?

Comment: "[...] after 500 seconds [...]", I suppose you meant "milliseconds", correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should multiple `500` by `index + 1`, so that the first one happens in `500ms`, the second in `1000ms`, etc.

```
setTimeout(function() {go(element)}, 500 * (index + 1));
```

Right now, you iterate over all of them, and tell each of them `500ms from now, do this`.  So, `500ms` from now, they each do it.

Comment: Super simple and effective.  Other answers attempt to ensure proper timing on chaining, but I suspect the human eye won't notice a millisecond or two of overlap / disconnect.

Comment: I think given the question "How can it so the first one starts moving after 500 seconds from start time, the second one starts after 1000 from start time, etc?" - the other ones are actually more likely to not start at the proper time (if each one takes `1ms` to do it's logic and schedule the next one, then after 1000 items, we're off by a second).

Comment: But the title of the question is asking for them to occur "back-to-back"; implying relation.  You're right, there may be logic overhead, but they will occur one after the other rather than allowing overlap.

Comment: that's true, there is some ambiguity as to which one he really wants.  in the end it doesn't really matter since the animation is 200ms and the delay between is 500

Comment: I'm really confused now. Is it `500-animation(200)-500-animation(200)-500-...` or `500-animation(200)-300-animation(200)-300-...`?

Comment: Wow thanks! Great solution. Simple and effective, i agree @cale_b

Answer (score 1):

Use `Promise`s and `reduce`.  Wait to start the next animation until after the previous finishes.

If you want to wait to begin the initial animation, wrap the whole chaining in a `setTimeout()`.

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("ul > li")).reduce((prev, curr) => {
  return prev.then(function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      $(curr).animate({
        opacity: 0.2
      }, 1000, function() {
        resolve();
      });
    });
  });
}, Promise.resolve());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Hello</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

They are all happening simultaneously, because all the `setTimeout`s are called inside the `each` which doesn't take long to loop the list of elements (merely a few milliseconds). If you want to chain them, then use the `complete` callback of [`jQuery#animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to signal for the next animation to start:

```
function iterate() {
    var $list = $(".mini"),                                // get the whole list of elements
        i = 0;                                             // i is the index of the currently animated element from list

    function next() {                                      // the function that when called will get the current element from list (if exists) and starts that element's animation
        if(i < $list.length) {                             // if there is still un-animated elements in $list
            setTimeout(function() {                        // animate the current element
                go($list.eq(i), next);                     // specify that next will be called when the current element's animation is done
            }, 500);
            i++;                                           // increment i of course
        }
    }

    next();                                                // call next to start the magic
}

function go(element, complete) {                           // go will take an element to be animated, and a function that will be called when that animation is done
    element.animate({left: "500px"}, 200, complete);       // simply call animate with that additional function (see jQuery#animate docs)
}
```

Comment: Is `list.eq(0)` correct? I think you're missing the `$` and it should use `i`, right? so `$list.eq(i)` maybe?

Comment: Great solution! Thank you!